# Trying to run Rodeo ('there was an error running python', 'Jupyter is not installed')

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, rodeo

When I try to run Rodeo, I get this error:

[image: Rodeo Error Message]

I am using Enthought distribution on Mac.  I just upgraded to run Python 3.5, everything runs OK in Enthought and Jupyter is installed and running fine.

How do I go about fixing this issue with Rodeo?

Comment: I was able to get Rodeo running by changing "Python Command" to python3 and doing a pip3 install for all the library's that were missing (Jupyter, Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib).  Rodeo is working now, but I don't really understand what is happening.  It would be nice if someone could explain.

Comment: I did the same @sslack88, but unfortunately I cannot get the built-in terminal to work.   I get a:
"Missing file or command: /Applications/Rodeo.app/Contents/Resources/conda/python.exe
Manually fix your python command in the Preferences, or ask the community for help:"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom right window of rodeo interface.
Then click on Packages. You will get a search button. type jupyter in the search. It will show jupyter package with a Install Package Button. Click on it and restart the terminal...